# Running a master query and a query of queries

Tags: sql, mysql, coldfusion, cfml

The following is code I'm running to `FIRST`, `SECOND`, `THIRD` and so on until `SEVENTH` with a master query and a query of query.

As it's clear that I'm using the master query for each of `FIRSTCONN`, `SECONDCONN` etc., I want to have only one master query and the rest subqueries.

1. Is this an efficient way to do so?
2. How can I make my code efficient?

```
<!--- QoQ for FIRSTCONN --->
<!--- Master Query --->
<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master1">
SELECT DATE(Timedetail) as FIRSTCONN, COUNT(Timedetail) as FIRSTOccurances, EVENTS 
FROM  MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = "FIRST" 
GROUP BY FIRSTCONN ;
</cfquery> 

<!--- Detail Query --->
<!--- <cfdump var = "#master#"> --->
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail1">
SELECT  *
FROM master1 
WHERE FIRSTCONN  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
AND FIRSTCONN  <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">;
</cfquery>  

<!--- QoQ for SECONDCONN --->
<!--- Master Query --->
<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master2">
SELECT DATE(Timedetail) as SECONDCONN, COUNT(Timedetail) as SECONDOccurances, EVENTS 
FROM  MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = "SECOND" 
GROUP BY SECONDCONN ;
</cfquery> 

<!--- Detail Query --->
<!--- <cfdump var = "#master#"> --->
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail2">
SELECT  *
FROM   master2 
WHERE  SECONDCONN  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
AND    SECONDCONN  <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">;
</cfquery>
```

Comment: @Matt Busche I tested the dump of master query, it's not pulling up any details for SECONDCONN. That is I can only see three columns as of now, namely, timedetail, firstOccurances and events. I belive UNION is not working

Comment: `union` is perfectly valid SQL. You can try with a `union all` but since the rows are different you shouldn't have different results. Using just `union` eliminates any duplicate rows and `union all` retains all rows

Answer (score 2):

You could use a UNION to run one master query

```
<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="master1">
SELECT DATE(Timedetail) as FIRSTCONN, COUNT(Timedetail) as FIRSTOccurances, EVENTS 
FROM  MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = "FIRST" 
GROUP BY FIRSTCONN
UNION
SELECT DATE(Timedetail) as SECONDCONN, COUNT(Timedetail) as SECONDOccurances, EVENTS 
FROM  MyDatabase
WHERE EVENTS = "SECOND" 
GROUP BY SECONDCONN;
</cfquery>
```

and then in your QoQ reference the correct column name

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail1">
SELECT  *
FROM master1 
WHERE FIRSTCONN  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
AND FIRSTCONN  <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#"     cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
AND EVENTS = 'FIRST';
```

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail2">
SELECT  *
FROM   master1
WHERE  SECONDCONN  >= <cfqueryparam value="#form.startdate#"     cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
AND    SECONDCONN  <  <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1,form.enddate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
AND EVENTS = 'SECOND';
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seven connections, I mean I'll have to UNION till SEVENTHCONN. Do you think that this will take less time as compared to what I have presently?

Comment: you should set it up and time each one. It should be faster.